# Reference request: construction of Chern classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-cohomology

I am looking for a reference on splitting principle for etale cohomology of simplicial schemes (over arbitrary field k). I found a paper by Schechtman, "On the delooping of chern character and Adams operations", where chern classes are introduced in Grothendieck style, for a given cohomology theory, and the projective bundle formula is stated as a required axiom for the cohomology theory. It will be appreciated if someone can direct me to a reference where the same is explained, possibly with more details.

Comment: Have you looked through http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1385.pdf? In particular, see pdf 37/144 beginning with Section 2.2 (Chern classes of algebraic bundles).